# Google Cloud Talent Solution fetch a job by requisitionId

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-talent-solution

I am wondering if it is possible to fetch a job by requisitionId in Google Cloud Talent Solution. `requisitionId` has to be unique across jobs so it seems like a natural candidate for looking a job up.

When a job is created the api returns a job `name` that can be used to look the job up:

> You can retrieve the details of a previously inserted job by sending a GET request to the Cloud Talent Solution. The URI should include the previously inserted job name returned by the original create request, as a URL parameter.

I'd like to avoid storing these names if possible. In my view storing them adds unnecessary complexity since I already have a unique `requisitionId`. To be clear the API does not let you add jobs with a duplicate `requisitionId`:

> Job projects/{my_app_id}/jobs/{google_assigned_id} already exists. Request ID for tracking: ... Related Job requisition ID: ...

So can I look up jobs by `requisitionId`?

I could parse the error message that's returned to get the job name..but that seems pretty brittle.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out the `list` method takes `requisitionId` so for a full, read-create-update cycle we can do:

```
const listRequest = {
  parent: `projects/${projectId}`,
  'filter': `companyName="${companyName}" AND requisitionId="${requisitionId}"`
}
const listResult = await jobService.projects.jobs.list(listRequest)
const existingJobs = listResult.data.jobs || [];

let existingJob = null
if (existingJobs && existingJobs.length > 0) {
  existingJob = existingJobs[0]
}

let googleJob
if (!existingJob) {
  const createRequest = {
    'parent': `projects/${projectId}`,
    'resource': {
      'job': {
        companyName,
        requisitionId,
        title,
        description,
        applicationInfo: {
          emails: ['email@example.com']
        }          
      }
    }
  }
  googleJob = await jobService.projects.jobs.create(createRequest)
  .then(result => result)
  .catch(resp => {
    console.error("ERROR")
    console.error(resp)
  })
} else {
  const patchRequest = {
    'name': existingJob.name,
    'resource': {
      'job': {
        companyName,
        requisitionId,
        title,
        description,
        applicationInfo: {
          emails: ['email@example.com']
        }          
      }
    }
  }
  googleJob = await jobService.projects.jobs.patch(patchRequest)
    .then(result => result)
    .catch(resp => {
      console.error("ERROR")
      console.error(resp)
    })
}
```

Docs: https://cloud.google.com/talent-solution/job-search/docs/reference/rest/v3/projects.jobs/list?authuser=0&hl=de

Notes:

- The double quotes in the `filter` parameter are important. It will not accept single quotes and will give a cryptic error message.
- The patch request cannot take a `parent` parameter even though everything else requires a parent parameter...

Comment: The notes about double quotes is the good point. I missed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

one can add it as custom attribute:

```
Map<String, CustomAttribute> attributes = new HashMap<>();

attributes
    .put("requisitionId", new CustomAttribute().setStringValue(requisitionId)
    .setFilterable(true));

Job job = new Job()
    ...
    .setCustomAttributes(attributes);

Job jobCreated = createJob(job);
String jobName = jobCreated.getName();
```

and then search for `requisitionId` with a custom attribute [filter](https://cloud.google.com/talent-solution/job-search/docs/search-filters):

```
 JobQuery jobQuery = new JobQuery().setCustomAttributeFilter(filter);
```

this is a little redundant, but `JobQuery` has no method `.setRequisitionId()`.

here's the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/jobs/v3/java/latest/).